# Change the format of my date string using C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to change the format of my date string using C#

From : `"16/06/2010"   dd/mmmm/yyyy`

To :   `"2010-06-16"   yyy-mmmm-dd`

Such as to allow me to insert in database. 
I used MySQL workbench.

How to do this? 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Take a look at [`MySqlDateTime`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-types-mysqldatetime.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("16/06/2010", "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
string dateString = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Do not confuse your format specifiers: `mm` stands for minutes, while `MM` or `MMM` - for a month.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
yourdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```